# Delayed evaluation with boost::mpl::eval_if

Tags: c++, boost, template-meta-programming

I have following code:

```
#include <boost/mpl/apply.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector_c.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/transform.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/equal.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/equal_to.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/not_equal_to.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/greater.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/less.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/plus.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/minus.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/multiplies.hpp>

#include <boost/type_traits/is_scalar.hpp>

template <typename N, typename Predicate >
struct next_if 
    : boost::mpl::eval_if<
            typename boost::mpl::apply<Predicate, N>::type, 
            // boost::mpl::apply<Predicate, N>,
            boost::mpl::next<N>,
            boost::mpl::identity<N>
            >
{};

template <typename N>
struct predic : boost::mpl::bool_<false>
{
};

template <int N>
struct predic <boost::mpl::int_<N>> : boost::mpl::bool_< (N > 0 && N < 100) >
{
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<next_if<boost::mpl::int_<10>, predic<boost::mpl::_1>>::type, boost::mpl::int_<11>>, "");

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles correctly with static_assert passed, as shown in godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/zcE9q8Trr .

However if I commented out "***typename boost::mpl::apply<Predicate, N>::type,***" and uncommented "***// boost::mpl::apply<Predicate, N>,***", the compilation failed due to early evaluation of **mpl_::arg<1>**.

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_64_0/boost/mpl/if.hpp: In instantiation of 'struct boost::mpl::if_<boost::mpl::apply<predic<mpl_::arg<1> >, mpl_::int_<10>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, boost::mpl::next<mpl_::int_<10> >, boost::mpl::identity<mpl_::int_<10> > >':
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_64_0/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp:37:41:   required from 'struct boost::mpl::eval_if<boost::mpl::apply<predic<mpl_::arg<1> >, mpl_::int_<10>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, boost::mpl::next<mpl_::int_<10> >, boost::mpl::identity<mpl_::int_<10> > >'
<source>:19:8:   required from 'struct next_if<mpl_::int_<10>, predic<mpl_::arg<1> > >'
<source>:40:87:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_64_0/boost/mpl/aux_/static_cast.hpp:24:47: error: 'value' is not a member of 'boost::mpl::apply<predic<mpl_::arg<1> >, mpl_::int_<10>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>'
   24 | #   define BOOST_MPL_AUX_STATIC_CAST(T, expr) static_cast<T>(expr)
      |                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The question is: why not "***typename boost::mpl::apply<Predicate, N>::type,***" forces an early evaluation of boost::placeholder mpl_::arg<1> to calculate the type of boost::mpl::apply<Predicate, N>, but a more innocent looking "***boost::mpl::apply<Predicate, N>***" does instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <type_traits>

#include <boost/mpl/apply.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector_c.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/transform.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/equal.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/equal_to.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/not_equal_to.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/greater.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/less.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/plus.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/minus.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/multiplies.hpp>

#include <boost/type_traits/is_scalar.hpp>

template <typename N, typename Predicate >
struct next_if 
    : boost::mpl::eval_if<
            boost::mpl::apply<Predicate, N>,
            boost::mpl::next<N>,
            boost::mpl::identity<N>
            >
{};


struct predic2
{
    template <typename N>
    struct apply : boost::mpl::bool_<boost::mpl::greater<N, boost::mpl::int_<0>>::value && boost::mpl::less<N, boost::mpl::int_<100>>::value>
    {
    };
} ;

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<next_if<boost::mpl::int_<10>, predic2>::type, boost::mpl::int_<11>>, "");

    return 0;
}
```

From the code above, however, **predic2** works well with **boost::mpl::apply<Predicate, N>** .

After I compiled the code with g++ -E to generate the source codes instead of compiling into final binary:
***g++ -E --std=c++17 -I ~/workspace/boost_1_82_0 test.cpp***

In case of **struct predic**, it is using a placeholder with boost::mpl::lambda:

```
typedef lambda<x>::type f;

Return type:    Metafunction Class. Semantics:  

If x is a Placeholder Expression in a general form X<a1,...an>, where X is a class template and a1,... an are arbitrary types, equivalent to

typedef protect< bind<
      quoten<X>
    , lambda<a1>::type,... lambda<an>::type
    > > f;

otherwise, f is identical to x.
```

it looks like boost::mpl::apply inherits from boost::mpl::protect<...>::apply<...> which does not have a ***type*** defined.

In case of  **struct predic2**, boost::mpl::apply inherits from predic2::apply directly, which in my example, has ***type*** defined.